# Can't pass parameters to stored procedure: parameters not supplied

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a WinForm desktop application for printer toners inventory. The data base is on a remote SQL Server and is made of just two table for orders and deliveries, with the stock quantity calculated just by keeping tracks of orders and deliveries through time. Plus a bunch of tables with manufacturers, models, categories and so forth.

I have this stored procedure for feeding the orders table:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spINSERTCARICO] (
    @MARCA VARCHAR(25),
    @MODELLO VARCHAR(25),
    @QTA INT,
    @OPERATORE CHAR(7),
    @CAUSALE VARCHAR(255))
AS
    DECLARE @MODELLOESATTO VARCHAR(25)
    SELECT @MODELLOESATTO = Modello FROM Modelli WHERE Modello = @MODELLO AND Marca = @MARCA
    INSERT INTO Carico 
        (Modello
        ,Qta
        ,DataCarico
        ,Operatore
        ,Note)
    VALUES
        (@MODELLOESATTO
        ,@QTA
        ,GETDATE()
        ,@OPERATORE
        ,@CAUSALE)
```

that is being executed from this method:

```
public static int InsertCarico(string _marca, string _modello, string _causale, int _qta)
{
    int insert = 0;
    try
    {
        if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed) connection.Open();
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spINSERTCARICO", connection))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@MARCA", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = _marca;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@MODELLO", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = _modello;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@QTA", SqlDbType.Int).Value = _qta;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@OPERATORE", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = System.Environment.UserName;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@CAUSALE", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = _causale;
            cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        }
        return insert;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

I always get the error

> Procedure or function 'spINSERTCARICO' expects parameter '@MARCA',
>   which was not supplied.

but I don't really see where is this coming from. While debugging I can see that variables are all set, and when manually on SSMS, the sproc works fine by

`EXEC spINSERTCARICO 'OLIVETTI','B0987',1,'_MYPIDN','PROVA'`

Where's the problem?

Thanks,
Davide.

Comment: Set the `CommandType`. `cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;` By Default value of the command type is **Text**.

Comment: @user1672994 I can't believe it. I've lost ONE HOUR debugging :(((

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default value of `CommandType` is Text. So `SqlCommand` object treat the provided SP name as command Text, until, you don't specify it to `StoredProcedure` . So set the `CommandType` as `cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure`;

```
public static int InsertCarico(string _marca, string _modello, string _causale, int _qta)
{
    int insert = 0;
    try
    {
       if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed) connection.Open();
       using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spINSERTCARICO", connection))
       {
           cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
           cmd.Parameters.Add("@MARCA", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = _marca;
           cmd.Parameters.Add("@MODELLO", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = _modello;
           cmd.Parameters.Add("@QTA", SqlDbType.Int).Value = _qta;
           cmd.Parameters.Add("@OPERATORE", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = System.Environment.UserName;
           cmd.Parameters.Add("@CAUSALE", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = _causale;
           insert = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
       }

       return insert;
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
       Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
       return 0;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do these 2 changes:

```
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure; // tell that's an SP

cmd.Parameters.Add("@MARCA", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = _marca;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@MODELLO", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = _modello;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@QTA", SqlDbType.Int).Value = _qta;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@OPERATORE", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = System.Environment.UserName;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@CAUSALE", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = _causale;

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); // don't expect any return value
```

Comment: Why not expecting any return value? I'm using that to inform the user about success/failure of the operation. Is there a better way?

Comment: @DavideVitali `ExecuteScalar()` is used to retrieve the first value of a resulting `SELECT`, which your SP doesn't execute (it just inserts data). An enough severe error on the SP will pop up an SQL Exception and will jump to your generic catch.

Answer (score 0):

My best guess would be to make sure

> _marca

is not null or empty and add

> cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

just under your using statement and don't expect a return value,
like so

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spINSERTCARICO", connection))
{
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure; //Add this

    cmd.Parameters.Add("@MARCA", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = _marca;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@MODELLO", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = _modello;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@QTA", SqlDbType.Int).Value = _qta;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@OPERATORE", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = System.Environment.UserName;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@CAUSALE", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = _causale;

    if(cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0){
        //Change to this
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code -

```
public static int InsertCarico(string _marca, string _modello, string _causale, int _qta)
{
    int insert = 0;
    try
    {
        if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed) connection.Open();
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spINSERTCARICO", connection))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@MARCA", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = _marca;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@MODELLO", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = _modello;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@QTA", SqlDbType.Int).Value = _qta;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@OPERATORE", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = System.Environment.UserName;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@CAUSALE", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = _causale;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

It seems that you missed to provide command type.